# How can i convert Blob Object to a file and send it to the server

Tags: javascript, ajax, blob, form-data

I want to convert a blob mp3 audio object in javascript to a file and send to the server.

So this is my code:

```
function createDownloadLink(blob,encoding) {

    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var au = document.createElement('audio');
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    var link = document.createElement('a');

    // Put in the server

    var token = $("#token").val();

    var formData = new FormData();
    

    formData.append("_token", token);
    formData.append('audio', blob);
    
    $.ajax('https://myip/audio', {
        method: "POST",
        data: formData,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
}
```

The response is for the server is the following:

```
{"_token":"3Qtbk53PLvzTzDBZrYwZY9WrHC7I6jmy9G6Aj6zw","audio":{}}
```

When i make console.log to the blob object appear this

```
Blob {size: 32914, type: "audio/mpeg"}
size: 32914
type: "audio/mpeg"
__proto__: Blob
arrayBuffer: ƒ arrayBuffer()
size: (...)
slice: ƒ slice()
stream: ƒ stream()
text: ƒ text()
type: (...)
constructor: ƒ Blob()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Blob"
get size: ƒ size()
get type: ƒ type()
__proto__: Object
```

Any ideas to solve this?

Comment: what do you get on console.log(formData) after apending values?

Comment: The issue could be in the server code, you should post it

Comment: You get blobs like `$_FILES['audio']` in PHP on the Server when you send via `FormData`. You should also put a 3rd argument in `formData.append`, so you have a filename with an extension.

Answer (score 0):

Following snippets converts a `blob` to `file` and appends it to the formdata

```
const blobFile = new File([blob], 'your_file_name');
formData.append("audio", blobFile);
```

However `blob` should work fine as well, as file is also a blob.

Comment: I was trying and does not works so maybe is on the hearder i need to put anything?

Comment: @ManuelBoludaGonzalez what you get with `console.log(formdata.getAll)`

Comment: I think using the `File` constructor in this case would be pointless, since you should be able to just `formData.append` the Blob... and you should give the `formData.append` a 3rd argument for the filename, with an extension.

Comment: @StackSlave thanks for the downvote and comment, however I have already explained to OP that blob will work the same as a file object. Read the answer again

Comment: Seems like a pointless answer then, since OP already did that.

Comment: If using new File([blob], 'your_file_name');
it's causing issue with calling File() constructor on IE11 with error "Object doesn't support this action".
is there a way to support new File() on IE11 or converting a blob file to file type without using new File() ?